# Vue3 define ref as number without typescript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a vue2 component with composition API. In the script setup section I defined

```
const val = ref(1);
onMounted(() => {
  val.value = props.maxVal; //maxVal exists
  console.log(val.value)
//log gives value as number
});
const diff = computed(() => {
  return props.maxVal - val.value;
```

The last line gives the error `Cannot convert object to primitive value`. In the log it appears as if val.value is an integer as needed. What's wrong? How do I cast a ref in Vue3 without typescript correctly?

Comment: I guess props.maxval is an object not an int, and you have an error when trying to set val.value

Comment: Post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Marc  ís there a playground providing Vue3?

Comment: https://sfc.vuejs.org/

Comment: Is there a console? Since the error spits on the console but the page works.

Answer (score 0):

This code example work normaly

```
<template>
  <div>diff : {{ diff }}</div>
</template>

<script>
import {
  createComponent,
  computed,
  onMounted,
  ref,
} from "@vue/composition-api";

export default createComponent({
  name: "CompositionCounter",
  props: {
    maxVal: {
      type: Number,
      default: 15,
    },
  },
  setup(props) {
    const val = ref(1);
    onMounted(() => {
      val.value = props.maxVal - 10; //maxVal exists
      console.log(val.value);
      //log gives value as number
    });
    const diff = computed(() => {
      return props.maxVal - val.value;
    });

    return {
      diff,
    };
  },
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I see no difference. maxVal is actually defined as number. My HTML even works but keeps spitting this error.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you got exception in  `computed()` method/property then I think you need to cast `val.value` to integer/float using `parseInt() or parseFloat()` i.e.

```
const diff = computed(() => {
  return props.maxVal - parseInt(val.value);
});
```

If still face error then debug `props.maxVal` and try to find, is it number or object. In case it's a number then, try following snippet:

```
const diff = computed(() => {
  let evaluatedValue = parseInt(props.maxVal) - parseInt(val.value);
  props.maxVal = evaluatedValue;
  return evaluatedValue;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't help either.